# NullReferenceException from InitializeComponent on upgrading to WPF 4 w/ generic type arguments

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, generics

I just began upgrading all of our client projects to .NET 4, and we're using WPF. All of my views inherit from a base class that extend UserControl, it is a code only base class with a single generic type argument: BaseView. Prior to upgrading to .NET 4, I simply specified the x:TypeArgument and everything worked fine, but after upgrading I now get a NullReferenceException on the InitializeComponent() call. The xaml file is set to Page and MsBuild:Compile, I tried setting it to Resource as I read somewhere but that doesn't even build. If I create a code file that inherits from that, say AddressView : BaseView, and use that, it works just fine. Is there a way to continue to specify the type arguments in my XAML file instead?

UPDATE: Adding deeper exception/stack trace:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack Trace:

at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, Boolean onlyLoadOneNode, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Boolean shouldPassLineNumberInfo, IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, XamlContextStack`1 stack, IStyleConnector styleConnector)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)

UPDATE 2: Maybe you're right, I just upgraded a separate project and it's not getting that error on the same machine, inheriting from the same base class. That is super odd, will start removing items from the view with the issue to try to find the issue.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like an error is being thrown in your code - you can find this by setting a higher level of exception handling in the debugger.

In Visual Studio, key Ctrl-Alt-E to bring up the Exceptions window, then ensure that Common Language Runtime Exceptions is checked in both columns, then run your code.

Execution will break at the line of code where the error is occurring, it should be easy enough to fix from there (if not, post the code and the Exception text).

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried that, doesn't work, still throws directly on the InitializeComponent() line, even tried to step into it and it gives the same thing but on the first line of the XAML where the control is defined. On of the views will throw a bit better exception, I tried Googling it though and got nothing that seemed relevant, will update original post with that exception.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace you get at InitializeComponent? This is actually much more useful than the exception you see in the markup, as it is closer to the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's the generic type argument - it used to work in 3.5. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750476.aspx:

> In WPF and when targeting .NET Framework version 4, you can use XAML 2009 features together with x:TypeArguments but only for loose XAML (XAML that is not markup-compiled). Markup-compiled XAML for WPF and the BAML form of XAML do not currently support the XAML 2009 keywords and features. If you need to markup compile the XAML, you must operate under the restrictions noted in the "XAML 2006 and WPF Generic XAML Usages" section.